# How can i put a small dot?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Question: I have been working on some geometric figures. In the given MWE i want to put dots at all points (namely A B C M and N).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\Huge
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,5);
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(0,3){A}
\tkzDefPoint(3,0){C}
\tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$A$}
\tkzLabelPoint[left](B){$B$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below,yshift=0mm](C){$C$}
\tkzDrawSegment[black!60!black](A,C)
\tkzMarkRightAngle[fill=blue!20,size=0.25](A,B,C)
\tkzDefPoint(4.5,0){M}
\tkzDefPoint(0,4.5){N}
\tkzLabelPoint[right,below](M){$M$}
\tkzLabelPoint[left](N){$N$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following `\foreach` construct will add a small circular black-filled node at each point you chose.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\Huge
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,5);
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(0,3){A}
\tkzDefPoint(3,0){C}
\tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$A$}
\tkzLabelPoint[left](B){$B$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below,yshift=0mm](C){$C$}
\tkzDrawSegment[black!60!black](A,C)
\tkzMarkRightAngle[fill=blue!20,size=0.25](A,B,C)
\tkzDefPoint(4.5,0){M}
\tkzDefPoint(0,4.5){N}
\tkzLabelPoint[right,below](M){$M$}
\tkzLabelPoint[left](N){$N$}
\foreach \n in {A,B,C,M,N}
  \node at (\n)[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: IF i wann put a dot at any single coordinate then what?

Comment: Just the same `\node at (x,y) [circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt]{};`